# ¿Cómo calcular Edad en un script bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Necesito realizar un script que solicite el año de nacimiento de la persona y calcule la edad, la cantidad de veces que el usuario lo desee. Luego que muestre en pantalla la edad de la persona y un mensaje si es mayor de edad o es menor de edad.

Tengo realizado eso pero no me funciona, agradezco su ayuda.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "¿En que año naciste?";
  EDAD=$(($(date +%Y) $YEAR));
  read EDAD;
  echo "Su edad es: $EDAD";
  if [ $EDAD -lt 18 ]; then
  echo "Usted es menor de edad";
  else
  echo "Usted es mayor de edad";
  fi
```

Answer (score 4):

¡Hola! Creo que estás pensando como un programador en Python. En Bash no puedes asignar así una variable y esperar que funcione. El error del script estaba en la variable EDAD, que se limitaba a registrar el año actual (y lógicamente eso siempre iba a ser "mayor de edad").
Prueba con esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "¿En que año naciste?"
read ANIO
let EDAD=$(date +%Y)-$ANIO
echo "Su edad es: $EDAD"
if [ $EDAD -lt 18 ]
    then
    echo "Usted es menor de edad"
else
    echo "Usted es mayor de edad"
fi
```

Para que se repita infinitamente usa

```
while True
do
    #El codigo que sea
done
```

Comment: Muy amable voy a probar y con lo del ciclo donde lo colocaría ya que supongo debo crear una ya que indica calcule la edad, la cantidad de veces que el usuario lo desee o no se si estoy errado. Gracias

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para reflejar eso :)

Comment: @Pythonis Que parte parece python?

Answer (score 1):

Esta bastante cerca, solo hay algunas cosas mal

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
echo "¿En que año naciste?"
read -r YEAR
EDAD=$(( $(date +%Y) - YEAR ))
echo "Su edad es: $EDAD"
if [ $EDAD -lt 18 ]; then
    echo "Usted es menor de edad"
else
    echo "Usted es mayor de edad"
fi
```

- no hacen falta los `;` al final de cada linea
- faltaba asignar `YEAR` antes de usarlo (`set -u` indicaria esto)
- faltaba la operacion `-`
- la indentacion, aunque no obligatoria, ayuda a leerlo

es una buena idea analizar los scripts con https://www.shellcheck.net/ para detectar errores comunes.

Comment: Esta bueno eso de shellcheck, gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma se muestran los años, meses y días, espero te sirva.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
opcion=0
while [ $opcion -ne 2 ]; do
    echo "1) Calcular edad"
    echo "2) Salir"
    echo "Elija una opcion: "
    read opcion
    case $opcion in
        1) echo "Calculando edad..."
            echo -n "Ingrese el año de nacimiento [ Ejemplo: 2022 ]: "
            read year
            echo -n "Ingrese el mes de nacimiento [ Ejemplo: Septiembre = 09 ]: "
            read month
            echo -n "Ingrese el dia de nacimiento [Ejemplo: 09]: "
            read day
            
            year_act=$(date +%Y)
            month_act=$(date +%m)
            day_act=$(date +%d)
            
            fyear=`expr $year_act - $year`
            if [ $month -gt $month_act ]
            then
                fyear=`expr $fyear - 1`
                aux=`expr $month - $month_act`
                fmonth=`expr 12 - $aux`
            else
                fmonth=`expr $month_act - $month`
            fi
            if [ $day -gt $day_act ]
            then
                fmonth=`expr $fmonth - 1`
                aux=`expr $day - $day_act`
                fday=`expr 30 - $aux`
            else
                fday=`expr $day_act - $day`
            fi
            
            echo -e "Tu tienes $fyear años, $fmonth meses, $fday dias de edad."
            
            if [ $fyear -ge 18 ]
            then
                echo -e "Felicidades eres Mayor de Edad\n"
            else
                echo -e "Lo sentimos eres menor de edad\n"
            fi
        opcion=0;;
        2) exit;;
        *) echo -e "opcion no valida, elija entre la opcion 1 y 2\n"
    esac
done
```

Acá el mismo script con salida a color.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
opcion=0
echo -e "\n\e[38:5:82mCALCULO DE EDAD\e[0m"
while [ $opcion -ne 2 ]; do
    
    echo -e "\e[38:5:39m1) Calcular edad\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[38:5:202m2) Salir\e[0m\n"
    echo -e "\e[38:5:87mElija una opcion: \e[0m"
    read  opcion
    case $opcion in
        1) echo -e "\n\e[38:5:93mCalculando edad...\e[0m"
            echo -en "\e[38:5:99mIngrese el año de nacimiento [ Ejemplo: 2022 ]: \e[0m"
            read year
            echo -en "\e[38:5:105mIngrese el mes de nacimiento [ Ejemplo: Septiembre = 09 ]: \e[0m"
            read month
            echo -en "\e[38:5:111mIngrese el dia de nacimiento [Ejemplo: 09]: \e[0m"
            read day
            
            year_act=$(date +%Y)
            month_act=$(date +%m)
            day_act=$(date +%d)
            
            fyear=`expr $year_act - $year`
            if [ $month -gt $month_act ]
            then
                fyear=`expr $fyear - 1`
                aux=`expr $month - $month_act`
                fmonth=`expr 12 - $aux`
            else
                fmonth=`expr $month_act - $month`
            fi
            if [ $day -gt $day_act ]
            then
                fmonth=`expr $fmonth - 1`
                aux=`expr $day - $day_act`
                fday=`expr 30 - $aux`
            else
                fday=`expr $day_act - $day`
            fi
            
            echo -e "\e[38:5:123mTienes\e[0m \e[38:5:201m$fyear\e[0m \e[38:5:123maños,\e[0m \e[38:5:201m$fmonth\e[0m \e[38:5:123mmeses\e[0m, \e[38:5:201m$fday\e[0m \e[38:5:123mdias de edad.\e[0m"
            
            if [ $fyear -ge 18 ]
            then
                echo -e "\e[38:5:82mEres Mayor de Edad\e[0m\n"
            else
                echo -e '\e[5m\e[31mEres menor de edad\e[0m\n'
            fi
        opcion=0;;
        2) exit;;
        *) echo -e "\e[5;33m*** Opcion no valida, elija entre la opcion 1 y 2 ***\e[0m\n"
    esac
done
```